# How to build the Minkovski projection in the Dantzig Wolf Decomposition

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, cplex, gurobi

I want to implement column generation by using Dantzig Wolf Decomposition.

In the algorithm, the feasible polyhedrons of the problem are represented as the convex combination of its extreme points and extreme rays. Thus we build a projection between the original problem and the master problem: x -> ∑μi*xi, where xi is the extreme points of the original feasible polyhedron.

I want to know how can I implement the projection in my code, i.e., for each μi, I can obtain its corresponding extreme point. Because for each extreme point, it is a list of the coordinates of the original variables. However the problem has a large number of variables so the list will be very long. If I save the coordinates for every μi, it will be expensive.

Comment: In DW we would only consider some interesting x(i) and not all of them. In that case this linear constraint is probably not that much of a deal.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So you mean I only need to save x(i) for those μ(i) which has been generated and added to the restrict master problems? I will have a try.